# How to handle a value being received as string or int in python?

Tags: python, rest, parsing, soap

My service works with both SOAP and REST.

When clients use SOAP to connect to my server I get their numerical input as integer / float values, while if they use REST for the same input I get string values. So far I had to use double parsing:

```
str(int(input_value)) or str(float(input_value))
```

which is not a good solution.

Is there any better way to deal with this in Python 2/3.x?

Or, is there a way of stopping REST numerical input being sent as strings?

=== Update ===

Sorry I forgot to mention. I need the input_value as a numeric value because first I need to apply some maths to it. ex. str(float(input_value) + 100)

Answer (score 1):

What's unclear from your question is why you're using

```
    str(int(input_value)) or str(float(input_value))
```

and converting to a string if you, as you say yourself, require a float. It may just be the wording of the question.

If you need every value as int/float and plan to later use maths on it.

1. I'd recommend float over int (unless you're absolutely sure about your input values)
2. A simple conversion to float should suffice. Regardless of where it's coming from just

   ```
   float(input_value)
   ```

and you'll have a float for your downstream steps.

Comment: Input_value could be string or int / float. 

If it's string, I cannot do the maths but I can print it. 
If it's numeric, I cannot print it but I can do the maths.

So in any case I would have to do ex. str(float(input_value)+100)

Comment: In that case, convert all to float and only convert to string when you print. Prior to that it's just unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand correctly but if you want to parse every number (int or float) and make it a string, you can just write:

```
str(input_value)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I need the input value to be int / float so I can do ex. str(float(input_value) + 100)

Comment: str(input_value + 100), if you have a int or a float it will work

Comment: input_value could also be string

Comment: ok so i think the bast way is to cast everything in int or float